# `nicematrix`, version 3.4 (2019/10/05) doesn't work as expected

Tags: nicematrix

After yesterday upgrading my MiKTeX installation, in which I got `nicematrix` of October 5, 2019, some old code doesn't work anymore as expected. For example (not really MWE):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\tikzset{
B/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
            raise=1pt, mirror},% for mirroring of brace
            thick,
            pen colour=black}
        }

\begin{document}
    \[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{RCL}%
    [code-after={\tikz\draw[B] (1-1.north west) -- (2-1.south west);
                 \tikz\draw[B] (3-1.north west) -- (4-1.south west);
                 \tikz\draw[B] (5-1.north -| 6-1.west) -- (6-1.south west);
                 \tikz\draw[B] (7-1.north west) -- (7-1.west |- 10-1.south);
                }
    ]
x_0 & = & 3     \\
x_1 & = & 1     \\[\jot]
%
c_12^0+c_2\cdot0\cdot2^0 & = & 3    \\
c_12^1+c_2\cdot1\cdot2^1 & = & 1    \\[\jot]
%
c_1       & = & 3   \\
2c_1+2c_2 & = & 1   \\[\jot]
%
c_1 & = & 3\\
c_2 & = & (1-2\cdot 3)/2\\
    & = & (-5)/2\\
    & = & -\frac{5}{2}
\end{NiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

doesn't produce braces defined in `code-after={...}` anymore. They should appear on the left sides of equations. Does anyone else experience similar issues? Or know for some work around for returning missing braces in above MWE.

**Edit:**
List of files used in above MWE is:

```
*File List*
standalone.cls    2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02b unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
nicematrix.sty    2019/10/05 v3.4 Several features to improve the typesetting o
f mathematical matrices with TikZ
    tikz.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
     pgf.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2019/07/20 v1.3b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
  pgffor.sty    2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
   expl3.sty    2019-10-02 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-10-02 L3 programming layer 
l3deprecation.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 v L3 backend support: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2019-05-28 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
   array.sty    2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
 amsmath.sty    2019/04/01 v2.17c AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  xparse.sty    2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
  spath3.sty    2019/02/12 v1.2 Functions for manipulating PGF soft paths
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 ***********
```

Situation with today (2015/10/15) upgrade was not changed.

**Problem is solved** by version 3.5 of `nicematrix` from 2019/10/13.

Comment: The output I get is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNmwo.png. It looks okay. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Image is almost black ... and yes, it seems to be complete. On my system the curly braces not appearing. As I said, I have recent version of MikTeX updated today.

Comment: Sorry about the image; my browser adds a white background. I have an also updated TeXLive, so the output should be the same, I think. My [`\listfiles`](https://pastebin.com/EUaRC6Tp) is slightly different. Notably I have `nicematrix` v3.5 (yours it 3.4), `graphics` v1.3c (yours is 1.3b, but I don't think this one is the problem), and `expl3`, `expl3-code`, `l3keys2e` and `xparse` 2019-10-11, while your versions are a little bit behind. My guess is that your `nicematrix` 3.4 that is causing the issue...

Comment: @LaTeXer, thank you for info. It seems that MikTeX doesn't yet have the latest versions of the packages (tested this morning). I will wait a while.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved by  version 3.5 of `nicematrix` from 2019/10/13.