# How can I write characters outside a table?

Tags: tables, formatting

I have a table and I would like to know how can  I write specific text outside the table, all around the table.

A simple example is this:

Above the table: a b c

RHS of the table: d e f

LHS of the table: g h i

Below the table: j k l

In a way that those letters are  aligned to the rows and columns respectively.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
        a & b & c \\
        \hline
        d & e & f \\
        \hline
        h & i & j \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Could someone tell me how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like as is shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512393/labeling-the-rows-of-a-matrix-with-letters ?

Comment: @Zarko yes. Though in my case requires also on the RHS and below the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant, but works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \newcommand{\myline}{\cline{2-4}}
    \newcommand{\noline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
        \noline{} & \noline{a} & \noline{b} & \noline{c} & \\
        \myline
        g & a & b & c & d \\
        \myline
        h & d & e & f & e \\
        \myline
        i & h & i & j & f \\
        \myline
        \noline{} & \noline{j} & \noline{k} & \noline{l} &
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments:

- I added a column each left and right without a vertical line `|` in front/after. So these columns are outside of the "outer frame" of the table.
- I didn't start or end with a `\hline` so that the first and last row are outside of the "outer frame" of the table.
- I use `\cline{2-4}` instead of `\hline` to have the vertical lines not extend to the two outermost columns.
- I use `\multicolumn{1}{c}` to remove the vertical lines around the cells in the first and last row.

Comment: oh, it is quite elegant. I only would define new command, for example `\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}` and than use `\mc{...}` in table body.

Comment: @Zarko: Good idea. I updated the answer with two new macros.

Comment: Thank you, works nice!

Comment: ...or just `\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}`.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun a version using a tikz matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix(table)[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center,text height=2ex,text depth=0.25ex, minimum width=1cm, fill=none, draw=black},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={draw=none}},
  column 5/.style = {nodes={draw=none}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
  row 5/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
  ] 
  {  & a & b & c &   \\
   g & a & b & c & d \\
   h & d & e & f & e \\
   i & h & i & j & f \\
     & j & k & l &  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative!

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[first-row,last-row,first-col,last-col,hvlines]
  & a & b & c \\
g & a & b & c & d \\
h & d & e & f & e \\
i & h & i & j & f \\
  & j & k & l \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\section{Manually}

\begin{tblr}{
hline{2-6} = {2-4}{solid},
vline{2-5} = {2-5}{solid},
}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 &  \\
a & X & Y & Z & b\\
c & U & S & T & d\\
e & N & M & O & f\\
g & J & K & L & h\\
  & i & ii & iii & \\
\end{tblr}

\section{Automated}

\begin{tblr}{
hline{2-\value{rowcount}} = {2-\numexpr\value{colcount}-1}{solid},
vline{2-\value{colcount}} = {2-\numexpr\value{rowcount}-1}{solid},
}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 &  \\
a & X & Y & Z & b\\
c & U & S & T & d\\
e & N & M & O & f\\
g & J & K & L & h\\
  & i & ii & iii & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can write `hline{2-Y} = {2-Y}{solid}` and `vline{2-Y} = {2-Y}{solid}` with the latest source code of `tabularray` (will be released as version `2021M` scheduled on 1st August). `X`, `Y`, `Z` always stand for the last three childs, respectively.