# Create a special table in latex

Tags: tables

I'd like to create a table as below.

[image]

How can I do it with latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You might be interested in the solutions to this very similar question: [How can I write characters outside a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518128/134144)

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{abc} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{abc} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{abc} \\
\cline{2-3}
abc & abc & abc \\
\cline{2-3}
abc & abc & abc \\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: @leandriis Thank you. It works.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you. It works.